# Looping Audio with React.js

Tags: reactjs, loops, audio

I think this is a rather simple question, but I am trying to self-learn React.js and am a bit confused about how audio loops. I understand looping when rendering and returning plain html audio tags, but I am not sure how to do it without. So far I have learned how to toggle play and pause buttons thanks to another StackOverflow question I found, but am not sure how to make the audio loop as well. I would like to keep the current code if possible (I tried to use the audio tags mentioned above instead when rendering, but it was hard to re-incorporate the image toggling again) and just learn how to incorporate looping into it. Any help or resources would be much appreciated! Below is the code I have reduced it to so far:

```js
export class PlaySound extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            play: true
        };

        this.url = "https://actions.google.com/sounds/v1/water/waves_crashing_on_rock_beach.ogg";
        this.audio = new Audio(this.url);
        this.togglePlay = this.togglePlay.bind(this);
    }

    togglePlay() {
        this.setState({
            play: !this.state.play
        });

        this.state.play ? this.audio.play() : this.audio.pause();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button
                    id="audioBtn"
                    onClick={this.togglePlay}> {this.state.play ? <PlayArrow /> : <Pause />}
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an `ended` listener to your `Audio` object in which you set the time back to `0` and start playing it again.

```
class PlaySound extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      play: true
    };

    this.url = "https://actions.google.com/sounds/v1/water/waves_crashing_on_rock_beach.ogg";
    this.audio = new Audio(this.url);
    this.audio.addEventListener('ended', function () {
      this.currentTime = 0;
      this.play();
    }, false);
    this.togglePlay = this.togglePlay.bind(this);
  }

  // ...
}
```

```js
class PlaySound extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      play: false
    };

    this.url = "https://actions.google.com/sounds/v1/water/air_woosh_underwater.ogg";
    this.audio = new Audio(this.url);
    this.audio.addEventListener('ended', function () {
      this.currentTime = 0;
      this.play();
    }, false);
    this.togglePlay = this.togglePlay.bind(this);
  }

  togglePlay() {
    const wasPlaying = this.state.play;
    this.setState({
      play: !wasPlaying
    });

    if (wasPlaying) {
      this.audio.pause();
    } else {
      this.audio.play()
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          id="audioBtn"
          onClick={this.togglePlay}> {this.state.play ? "Pause" : "Play"}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<PlaySound />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I can't find out the document for this one. Could you please?

Answer (score 4):

you can just set `loop = true`

```js
togglePlay() {
        this.setState({
            play: !this.state.play
        });

        this.state.play ? this.audio.play() : this.audio.pause();
        this.audio.loop = true;
    }
```